# TransferToSuccessPage() when SPLongOperation is running

Tags: application-pages, development

I am using SPLongOperation() , the scenario is:

```
Splongoperation operation=new splongoperation();
operation.begin();

try {
  /// all working... 
}
catch(exception excep)
{
  sputility.transfertoerrorpage(excep.message);
}

sputility.tranfsertosuccesspage("DOne");

operation.end(vvv);
```

but it is unable to transfer to the error or success page.

Is it possibly to do with the transfer inside splongoperation()?

Answer (score 1):

Without having tried out the code, it looks to me as if you do a redirect before your transaction has finished. This will end code execution.

Are you aware that you can redirect using the

operation.End("/mysuccesspage.aspx", Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEndResponse, HttpContext.Current, "");

to redirect to where you want?

Comment: i want to redirect to SPUtility.Transfertosuccesspage().. is it possible to redirect to this page with opeartion.End()?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Have a look at MBSurf's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the reflector, SPUtility.TransferToSuccessPage has the success page hardcoded to ~/layouts/success.aspx, so you are probably safe in doing

```
operation.End("success.aspx", SPRedirectFlags.RelativeToLayoutsPage, current, "");
```

to get to the official success page and have it work with SPLongOperation

Comment: i ll try this and will let u know.